# PostgreSQL does not automatically make use of available RAM for memory-intensive queries

Tags: linux, postgresql, database-performance

I'm running a database application on linux (ubuntu), using PostgreSQL. The application is very memory-intensive, so I gave the database server 64 GB of RAM (and 8 CPU cores).  Postgres does not seem to automatically detect and use the available RAM, and the application's queries run very slowly.  For instance, `top` says:

```
PID   USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
5958 postgres  20   0 16.5g  70m  66m R   99  0.1   8:00.83  postgres
4233 postgres  20   0     0    0    0 R    8  0.0   0:00.04  postgres
789  postgres  20   0 16.5g 408m 407m S    2  0.6   0:32.15  postgres 
4221 root      20   0 17336 1292  952 R    2  0.0   0:00.01  top     
1    root      20   0 24348 2232 1340 S    0  0.0   0:01.59  init
```

I tried increasing the kernel-side limits on SysV shared memory segments, via `/etc/sysctl.conf`...

```
kernel.shmmax=34359738368
kernel.shmall=2147483648
```

... but this had no effect, even after a reboot.  What should I try next?

Comment: This is a ServerFault or dba.stackexchange.com question.  I believe you need to adjust the memory-usage knobs for postgres itself, see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-resource.html for instructions

Comment: Also, I have revised your question so that it is clearer what you are asking.

Comment: Why do you think that using more RAM would be helpful?  Your `top` listing does not seem to support that assumption.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tuning commands you could apply to a postgres instance to try and make a better use of the available specs that you have, you can even modify the behaviour of specific performance variables using ALTER DATABASE if you want to allocate special resources to some specific databases.

I recommend that you read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/runtime-config-resource.html and just start trying out what values boost your performance.